# Let $\operatorname{id}$ be the identity map of $C[0, 1]$ . Pick out the true statements.

Tags: general-topology

Let $V_i=(C[0, 1], d_i), i = 1, 2$ be the metric spaces where

$$d_1(f, g) = \sup_{x∈[0,1]} |f(x) − g(x)|\\
d_2(f, g) =\int_{0}^{1}|f(x) − g(x)|dx \,$$

Let $\operatorname{id}$ be the identity map of $C[0, 1]$ . Pick out the true statements.

- a) $\operatorname{id} : V_1 \to V_2$ is continuous.
- b) $\operatorname{id} : V_2 \to V_1$ is continuous.
- c) $\operatorname{id} : V_1 \to V_2$ is a homeomorphism

i know that  $d_1 \ge  d_2$   so option  a)  and c)  is correct

is  It true ??

THanks  u

Comment: If c) is correct, then so are a), b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct for a)

Hint for b):

Check continuity at $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=0$

Comment: thanks @LDM      what about  option c) ???

Comment: @stupid: c) is obviously false because b) is false

Comment: @stupid: inverse of the identity map is again identity

Comment: @LDM...thanks  dear